# How does autoscaling work with an Azure web application?

Tags: azure, autoscaling

I'm curious how auto scaling works with an Azure web application, specifically how each new instance gets a copy of the source code for the application.

Is this what happens, or is the source stored somewhere and each new instance points to it?

Comment: Are you using Azure Wbsites, Cloud Services or Virtual Machine to run your application. Reason I ask this is because auto scaling works differently for each of them though serving single purpose of running your application across multiple instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire virtual machine is duplicated.  So usually you might have just one database but multiple apps receiving and processing the requests.  If you need an "autoscaling" database too, then there are database solutions that handle syncronization across multiple machines, but in that case you're probably better off using Azure's native database which takes care of that.

Comment: I was under the impression that you shared a VM with other tenants

Comment: @kimsagro in Azure, a physical server might have a dozen vm's by different people. The servers are shared but the vm is your own, running on the server.  So it might have 4 of your vms and 5 other people's vms all running on a server, or 2 of your vms might be on one server and 2 on another server etc.